# Ajax setting 'context' does not affect 'data's location

Tags: javascript, ajax, syntax

the following Ajax works

```
function Retrieve(el) {
    var table = this;
    this.el = el;
    this.fetchInfo = function () {
        $.ajax('data.html', {
            context: table,
            <!-- QUESTION HERE -->
            data: {
                location: table.data('location')
            },
            success: function (response) {
                this.el.find('.info').html(response).fadeIn();
            },
        }
        }
```

but I am wondering why I cannot replace `table.data` with `this.data` on the denoted line. Since I set the context to `table` variable, `this` now should be set to whatever `table` is referring to right? This holds true in the context of other members of the Ajax object (including `success`), but not for the members of `data`. Why is this the case?

`data('name')` extracts value from a tag with attribute `data-name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=%24.ajax) of `$.ajax()`, I found that the `context` gets set to `callbackContext` variable. This gets with use `success`, `error`, `beforeSend`, `complete`, but not with `data` option.

AJAX options gets assigned to a variable named `s`:

```
s = jQuery.ajaxSetup({}, options),
```

The data option gets converted to string, but `callBackContext` is not used.

```
// Convert data if not already a string
if (s.data && s.processData && typeof s.data !== "string") {
    s.data = jQuery.param(s.data, s.traditional);
}
```

So it is necessary to set specify the element for `data` using a variable other than `this`.

Comment: I just rolled back to the original question, which I had before you asked me for more code.

Comment: that's not very helpful given that it completely destroys the context (no pun intended) of the answer I had given.  You wanted to know how to use `this` within the `data:` block, and the answer I gave you told you how - by fixing what `this` is when `fetchInfo` gets called.

Answer (score 1):

The `context` variable you've given only applies within the `success` callback, and doesn't change anything for any of the other parameters passed to `$.ajax`.

The answer therefore depends on how you actually *call* `fetchInfo`.   The `data:` variables will be resolved in whatever context `fetchInfo` has.  Given you're experiencing problems, this suggests that you are *not* calling the function with your `Retrieve` object as its context.

**EDIT** this line is your problem:

```
this.el.on('click', 'button', this.fetchInfo);
```

just because you've referred to `this.fetchInfo`, doesn't make `this` the context when it's subsequently invoked.  Try this instead:

```
this.el.on('click', 'button', $.proxy(this.fetchInfo, this));
```

Comment: Just to clarify, is going inside a `function` that kicks in the `context` variable to replace `this`'s context? I am not any experiencing problems, but I just wanted to know why. How would I change my code such that `this.data` could replace `table.data`?

Comment: You said that you "_cannot replace `table.data` with `this.data`_", suggesting you had tried and failed.  You _can_ replace it, so long as `fetchInfo` is called as `this.fetchInfo()` or `table.fetchInfo()`, thus ensuring that `this` inside `fetchInfo` has the same value as it has _outside_.

Comment: Okay, I agree with everything that you say, but I still have not found out why the context is different for a callback and non-callback member. Could you please tell me why there is the difference?

Comment: @Forethinker for that you would have to include some extra code in your question showing how you call the `Retrieve` function, and also how you call `fetchInfo`.

Comment: Okay. I have included the extra code. I think `$(document).ready(function() {` part should suffice, but I included other parts of code just to be sure.